# FirebaseAuthWebException not found. Please verify the AAR

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine

I am adding Facebook SDK into my Unity Android project with Firebase. There are some files conflict in PlayServicesResolver so I force resolve it. But when I press the Facebook Login button. Error comes out.

> Java class com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthWebException not found.  Please verify the AAR which contains the com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthWebException class is included in your app.

Actually I usually face the similar problems many times, especially sometimes those sdk using different versions of PlayServiceResolver. I have tried reimport all the asset and force resolve. But these methods do not help. Or do I focus on the wrong folder? I have taken a look in the Android plugin folder but still get no idea. Anyone may help?

My Firebase is in 5.3.1 (it was 5.4.1 but it conflicts with other sdk after upgrading). My Unity is in 2018.2.14f1.

Answer (score 0):

include in your App level Gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
implementation project(path: ':loginwithgoogle_facebook_from_firebase')
```

call below code in your LoginActivity

```
LoginButton loginButton = findViewById(R.id.fbLogin_Buttin_ID);
new FacebookFIrebaseLogin(mActivity, loginButton, new ResponceClass() {
    @Override
    public void updateUI(FirebaseUser user) {...}});
```

Make sure you have google-services.json file download from Firebase console.

You can check my GitHub repository for a complete example

https://github.com/HemantSharmaDevloper/Login_with_Facebook_google_firebase